# How to make DialogFragment modal?

Tags: android, android-fragments, modal-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a DialogFragment :

```
public static class CharacteristicDialog extends DialogFragment {
        int mNum;

        static CharacteristicDialog newInstance(int num) {
            CharacteristicDialog f = new CharacteristicDialog();            
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("num", num);
            f.setArguments(args);
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mNum = getArguments().getInt("num");
            setStyle(STYLE_NO_INPUT, 0);        
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.characteristic_dialog, container, false);
            v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

I create it in my main Fragment like this :

```
        DialogFragment newFragment = CharacteristicDialog.newInstance(v.getId());
        newFragment.setShowsDialog(true);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

It shows well, but it is not modal (I can click on the sides and make actions on my main Fragment behind the dialog).

How do I make it modal ?

Thanks

Comment: `I can click on the sides and make actions on my main Fragment behind the dialog` That sounds really odd... Are you using native fragments or support library? Actionbarsherlock?

Comment: I am using the support lib, no Actionbarsherlock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just change `STYLE_NO_INPUT` то `STYLE_NORMAL` into your `setStyle()` method. 
For more info about DialogFragment styles and themes take look at docs: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: That was it thanks. I used STYLE_NO_FRAME instead of normal because it's a custom dialog.

Answer (score 19):

This worked for me.

```
myDialogFragment.setCancelable(false);
```